# How to prove that $\binom{k}{2}=\left\lfloor\frac{k^2}4\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{(k-1)^2}4\right\rfloor$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, inequality

I believe the following equation holds.

$$
\binom{k}2=\left\lfloor\frac{k^2}4\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{(k-1)^2}4\right\rfloor.
$$

But I can only prove one direction:

Since for any real numbers $a$ and $b$, $\lfloor a  \rfloor + \lfloor b  \rfloor \le  \lfloor a +b  \rfloor$, we have

$$
\begin{align*} 
\left\lfloor\frac{k^2}4\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{(k-1)^2}4\right\rfloor &\le \left\lfloor\frac{k^2}4+\frac{(k-1)^2}4\right\rfloor \\
&= \left\lfloor \frac{2k^2-2k}4+\frac{1}{4} \right\rfloor\\ 
&=\binom{k}2.
\end{align*} 
$$

How can the other side be proven?

Comment: There are at most $~4~$ cases  to manually consider, re $~k \equiv r \pmod{4} ~: ~r \in \{0,1,2,3\}.~$  Also, you may be able to get away with only considering $~k~$ odd or even.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Notice that one of $k-1, k$ is odd, and the other one is even, so $\bmod 4$ one of $(k-1)^2, k^2$ is $0$ and the other $1$, thus $\left\lfloor\frac{k^2}4\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{(k-1)^2}4\right\rfloor = \frac{k^2}4 + \frac{(k-1)^2}4 - \frac14 = \frac{2 k^2 - 2k}4 = \binom{k}2$.

Answer (score 2):

Observe two cases, one where $k$ is even and the other where $k$ is odd.

Observe that in either case,

$$\left\lfloor\frac{k^2}4\right\rfloor+\left\lfloor\frac{(k-1)^2}4\right\rfloor = \left\lfloor\frac{k^2}4+\frac{(k-1)^2}4\right\rfloor \\$$

This happens because in the case where $k$ is even, $\frac{k^2}{4}$ is integer, and when $k$ is odd, then, $\frac{(k-1)^2}{4}$ is an integer.

The following two lines of the solution are the same as before to conclude the proof. What is needed here is to realize that the inequality in your solution works as an equality for this case.

Comment: It is also nice.